# istio command to list registered services in internal service registry

Tags: istio

I am trying to list the list of services that are present in istio internal service registry. However, failed to do that, more specifically details added by service entry. Anyone knows the `istioctl` command to list the services ?
Ref- https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is detailed documentation [page](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#get-an-overview-of-your-mesh) about commands that does that.

> The proxy-status command allows you to get an overview of your mesh. If you suspect one of your sidecars isn’t receiving configuration or is out of sync then proxy-status will tell you this.
>
> ```
> $ istioctl proxy-status
> PROXY                                                  CDS        LDS        EDS               RDS          PILOT                            VERSION
> details-v1-6dcc6fbb9d-wsjz4.default                    SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-tfdvh     1.1.2
> istio-egressgateway-c49694485-l9d5l.istio-system       SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-75bdf98789-tfdvh     1.1.2
> istio-ingress-6458b8c98f-7ks48.istio-system            SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> istio-ingressgateway-7d6874b48f-qxhn5.istio-system     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> productpage-v1-6c886ff494-hm7zk.default                SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     STALE        istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> ratings-v1-5d9ff497bb-gslng.default                    SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> reviews-v1-55d4c455db-zjj2m.default                    SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> reviews-v2-686bbb668-99j76.default                     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-tfdvh     1.1.2
> reviews-v3-7b9b5fdfd6-4r52s.default                    SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istio-pilot-75bdf98789-n2kqh     1.1.2
> ```
>
> If a proxy is missing from this list it means that it is not currently connected to a Istiod instance so will not be receiving any configuration.
>
> - `SYNCED`  means that Envoy has acknowledged the last configuration  Istiod  has sent to it.
> - `NOT SENT`  means that Istiod hasn’t sent anything to Envoy. This usually is because Istiod has nothing to send.
> - `STALE`  means that Istiod has sent an update to Envoy but has not received an acknowledgement. This usually indicates a networking issue between Envoy and Istiod or a bug with Istio itself.

There is also similar command `istioctl proxy-config` it can be used to see how a given Envoy instance is configured. More details are also on the same documentation [page](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration).

Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

In case of `ServiceEntry` on pilot there is a debug endpoint:

```
localhost:8080/debug/registryz
```

For more information how to use it take a look at [this](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/telemetry/envoy-stats/) documentation page.

example:

```
kubectl exec $POD -c istio-proxy -- curl 'localhost:8080/debug/registryz' > service_registry
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, this command does not show anything added by serviceentry. I am looking for that.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added alternative method which should include `serviceentry` endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find the way to get the content of Istio registry in the convenient form using `istioctl`, but it's achievable using slightly different approach.

[Piotr Malec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61369456/9521610) was right (please consider to upvote his answer too ), Pilot's debug interface can provide the list you've mentioned in the question. And the request to Istio Pilot can be sent using any Pod's envoy sidecar. Both ports are valid for the request: 15014 and 8080, and give the same result.

For this example I'm using Pilot's own envoy sidecar. I'm also using jq on my machine to get services' names from the JSON response.

Imagine we have three `ServiceEntry` in the cluster:

```
$ kubectl get serviceentry 
NAME               HOSTS                             LOCATION        RESOLUTION   AGE
httpbin            [httpbin.org]                                     DNS          18d
httpbin-com-ext    [httpbin.org]                     MESH_EXTERNAL   DNS          22d
wikipedia-org-se   [wikipedia.org *.wikipedia.org]   MESH_EXTERNAL   NONE         22d
```

The following sequence of commands gives us the list of services including the services defined by `ServiceEntry` objects:

```
# create a shortcut to Istio Pilot pod
$ PILOT=$(kubectl get -A pods --selector=istio=pilot -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')
# Create shortcut to Istio Pilot namespace
$ PILOT_NS=$(kubectl get -A pods --selector=istio=pilot -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.namespace}')

# Get the list of services in Istio mesh and filter their names using jq
$ kubectl exec $PILOT -n $PILOT_NS -c discovery -- curl -s 'localhost:15014/debug/registryz' | jq '.[].hostname'
    # or
$ kubectl exec $PILOT -n $PILOT_NS -c istio-proxy -- curl -s 'localhost:15014/debug/registryz' | jq '.[].hostname'
```

The output:
( Note the last several entries.)

```
"ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-citadel.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-galley.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-pilot.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-policy.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local"
"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
"kubernetes.test.svc.cluster.local"
"metrics-server.metrics.svc.cluster.local"
"productpage.default.svc.cluster.local"
"prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local"
"ratings.default.svc.cluster.local"
"reviews.default.svc.cluster.local"
"httpbin.org"
"httpbin.org"
"wikipedia.org"
"*.wikipedia.org"
```

You can find more information about Debug Handlers on Istio github page:

- [Istio - Debug interface](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/pilot/pkg/proxy/envoy/v2#debug-interface)